# Extract text between ( - opening brace and ) - closing brace

Tags: bash, unix

I need to extract the fields from the below text between `(` and `)` in bash.

**Case 1**

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE "Procedure_Name"
(
field1 IN DATE,
field2 IN VARCHAR2,
field3 IN INTEGER
)
```

I need the following output:

Output 1:

```
field1 DATE, field2 VARCHAR2, field3 INTEGER
```

Output 2:

```
field1, field2, field3
```

**Case 2**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "Procedure_Name" (field1 IN DATE,field2 IN VARCHAR2,field3  INTEGER)
```

I need the following output:

Output 1:

```
field1 DATE, field2 VARCHAR2, field3 INTEGER
```

Output 2:

```
field1, field2, field3
```

Comment: Adding "It's urgent" and similar messages is not always well received, and won't apply forever, while your question will linger (possibly helping others) long after you have received an answer.

Comment: Also, you should tell us what you have tried; and you need to be more careful with your specification: must this be done *in* bash, in a bash script, in some program you can call from bash?

Answer (score 2):

Output 1:

```
$ cat filename | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -o '\(.*\)'  | tr '()' '  ' | sed 's/[IN|OUT]//g'
```

Output 2:

```
$ cat filename | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -o '\(.*\)'  | tr '()' '  ' | sed 's/[IN|OUT]//g' | sed 's/[DATE|VARCHAR2|INTEGER]//g'
```

Comment: $cat t.txt
create or replace
PROCEDURE "Procedure_Name"
(
field1 IN DATE,
field2 IN VARCHAR2,
field3 IN INTEGER
)